# Not able to persist the role mapped to the user

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am creating an application with Spring 4, Hibernate 4 having Spring security

Users have roles assigned to them, but when I tried to create the user, it not able to save the user it is giving me exception on Browser below the field of role

```
Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String[]] to required type [java.util.Set] for property userRoles; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
```

[@org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty @javax.persistence.ManyToMany @javax.persistence.JoinTable com.himanshu.blogger.model.Role] for value 2; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

My User model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BLOG_USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "MIDDLE_NAME")
    private String middleName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "STATE")
    private Integer state = State.ACTIVE.getState();

    @Transient
    private String stateName;

    @NotEmpty
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE_MAP", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") })
    private Set<Role> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

/*skipped getter, setters and some utility methods*/
```

Role model class

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ROLE_ID")
    private Integer roleId;

    @Column(name="ROLE_TYPE", length=20, nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String roleType=RoleType.USER.getRoleType();
/*skipped getters and setters*/
```

My controller methods for registering new user here I have added a model attribute also to load the roles in registration form

```
/**
     * This method will provide the medium to add a new user. 
     * By GET method it will identify that it has to load registration page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newUser(ModelMap model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        return "registration";
    }

    /**
     * This method will be called on form submission, handling POST request for
     * saving user in database. It also validates the user input
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

            System.out.println("save user : "+user);
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "registration";
            }

            if(!userService.isUniqueUser(user.getUserId())){
                FieldError userIdError =new FieldError("user","userId",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssoId", new String[]{user.getUserId()}, Locale.getDefault()));
                result.addError(userIdError);
                return "registration";
            }

            userService.saveUser(user);

            model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " registered successfully");

        //return "success";
        return "registrationsuccess";
    }

@ModelAttribute("blogRoleList")
    public List<Role> initializeProfiles() {
        return roleService.findAll();
    }
```

I have registered a convertor to convert role id to Role object

```
@Component
public class RoleIdtoRoleConverter implements Converter<Object, Role> {

    @Autowired
    RoleService roleService;

    public Role convert(Object roleIdObj) {

        System.out.println("covertor called with id " + roleIdObj.toString());
        Integer roleId = -1;
        try {
            roleId = Integer.parseInt((String) roleIdObj);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ConversionFailedException(TypeDescriptor.valueOf(String.class),
                    TypeDescriptor.valueOf(Role.class), roleIdObj, null);
        }

        System.out.println("covertor called with id " + roleIdObj.toString());

        Role role = roleService.findRoleById(roleId);
        System.out.println("Role = " + role);

        return role;
    }
```

Registered this convertor in my config class

```
@Autowired
    RoleIdtoRoleConverter roleIdToRoleConverter;

    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(roleIdToRoleConverter);
    }
```

Registration JSP file registration.jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user" class="form-horizontal">
<%--        <form:input type="hidden" path="userId" id="useId"/> --%>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="firstName">First Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:input type="text" path="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="firstName" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:input type="text" path="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control input-sm" />
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="lastName" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="userId">User ID</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${edit}">
                            <form:input type="text" path="userId" id="userId" class="form-control input-sm" disabled="true"/>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <form:input type="text" path="userId" id="userId" class="form-control input-sm" />
                            <div class="has-error">
                                <form:errors path="userId" class="help-inline"/>
                            </div>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <c:if test="${!edit}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="password">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <form:input type="password" path="password" id="password" class="form-control input-sm" />
                        <div class="has-error">
                            <form:errors path="password" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </c:if>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="email">Email</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:input type="text" path="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" />
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="email" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="userRoles">Roles</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:select path="userRoles" items="${blogRoleList}" multiple="true" itemValue="roleId" itemLabel="roleType" class="form-control input-sm" />
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="userRoles" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-actions floatRight" style="margin-left: 25px">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${edit}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"/> or <a href="<c:url value='/listUser' />">Cancel</a>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"/> or <a href="<c:url value='/listUser' />">Cancel</a>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

But am not able to figure out it is not able to save the data, I have printed the user object in controller it is showing Roles as blank array, did I am missing some things here, not able to get, any help and suggestions will be got.

**Adding Code for saving user**

Abstract dao class

```
public class AbstractDao <PK extends Serializable, T>{

    private final Class<T> persistantClass;

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao() {
        this.persistantClass=(Class<T>)((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    public void persistEntity(T entity) {
        this.getSession().persist(entity);
    }
    /* mor emethods to load data on based on object type */
}
```

User Dao implimentation calss

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<String, User> implements  UserDao{
    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        persistEntity(user);

    }
    /* more methods for fetching data from db*/
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve... Please post a MINIMAL example. You shouldn't dump your entire code, you should post the smallest amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you think if I remove some code from this, question will make sense, it is already having very precise code as I think.

Comment: @HimanshuMishra your code looks fine. How are you persisting the user object. Can you add that code here?

Comment: @Mustafa Added code for saving the user in DB

Comment: I tried reproducing the error you are facing in a Spring Boot project using the code that you have pasted, but I couldn't, i.e. the above code works fine for me. If you like, you can download the Spring Boot project here https://file.io/kCgwpI and try to compare it to yours.

Comment: @Mustafa Url did not work for me got response {"success":false,"error":404,"message":"Not Found"}

Comment: @HimanshuMishra, that link died. Please try this https://filetea.me/t1sU46IdG4uS6axBy79dXRtxw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem with my application.
The problem was with the dao method which was there to get `role` object from DB,
by mistake while writing the code I did made the call to same method, which executing recursively, so convertor was not able to get the `role` object from DB.